# Repository pattern with transactional query

Tags: go, repository-pattern, transactional-database

I am writing a service that can make a transactional query, (in this question I will be using GORM)

**UserService**

```
type userService struct {
    UserRepository  repository.IUserRepository
    TokenRepository repository.ITokenRepository
}

type IUserService interface {
WithTrx() IUserService
CommitTrx() error
RollbackTrx()

Create(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error)
...
...
}
```

here is some implementation of the service

***user.go***

```
func (s *userService) WithTrx() IUserService {
    newService := &userService{
        UserRepository:       s.UserRepository.WithTrx(),
        TokenRepository:      s.TokenRepository,
    
    }
    return newService
}
func (s *userService) Create(ctx context.Context, name string) (*model.User, error) {
... 
// s.UserRepository.Create() 
// then return the user, error 
...
}
```

and for the UserRepository.WithTrx() is basically just returning the interface itself

```
type psqlUserRepository struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

type IUserRepository interface {
    WithTrx() IUserRepository
    CommitTrx() error
    RollbackTrx()

    Create(ctx context.Context, u model.User) (*model.User, error)
...
}

func (r *psqlUserRepository) WithTrx() IUserRepository {
    return &psqlUserRepository{DB: r.DB.Begin()}
}
```

So when I need user service to create a user using transactional query, I just:

```
trx:= userserviceInstance.WithTrx()
user, err := trx.Create(ctx, name)
// err handling and rollback
commitErr := trx.CommitTrx()
```

Is there any similar approach like this? What is it called? I am not sure whether this is the right pattern to create a transactional query.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there are a few moments here.

The Repository pattern is normally used to hide the implementation details of a storage.

A Transaction is a technical detail which should not be exposed to the higher layers.

In other words the Repository interface (architectural element) you have shouldn't expose the transaction (technical details).

> Is there any similar approach like this? What is it called? I am not
> sure whether this is the right pattern to create a transactional query
> You may want to learn more about Unit of Work pattern which can be useful for your purpose.

You may take a look at Unit of Work Pattern.

Bellow are some examples which you may find useful:

- https://dev.to/techschoolguru/a-clean-way-to-implement-database-transaction-in-golang-2ba
- https://goenning.net/2017/06/20/session-per-request-pattern-go/
- https://pseudomuto.com/2018/01/clean-sql-transactions-in-golang/
- https://github.com/screwyprof/skeleton/blob/main/internal/pkg/adapter/postgres/certificate_repository.go